# Как правильно пишетcя предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правлильно писать (вариант 1,2)?

1.Указанные размеры и цвет тумбы Парус -1 венге/дуб беленый могут быть изменены под требования покупателя с дальнейшим пересчетом стоимости индивидуально. Для этого оформите заказ без его оплаты, укажите пожелания в комментариях к заказу и мы свяжемся с Вами для уточнения деталей.

2.Указанные размеры и цвет тумбы Парус -1 венге/дубА беленОГО могут быть изменены под требования покупателя с дальнейшим пересчетом стоимости индивидуально. Для этого оформите заказ без его оплаты, укажите пожелания в комментариях к заказу и мы свяжемся с Вами для уточнения деталей.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой компромисс между краткостью и стилистической аккуратностью.

> 1. Указанные размеры и цвет тумбы Парус-1 (венге / дуб беленый) могут быть изменены по требованию покупателя с дальнейшим пересчетом
>      стоимости индивидуально. Для этого оформите заказ без его оплаты,
>      укажите пожелания в комментариях к заказу, и мы свяжемся с Вами для
>      уточнения деталей.

В любом случае, лучше название цвета оставить в именительном падеже, а косую черту отбить пробелами (поскольку отделяется словосочетание).